# How can i know number of page in pagelayout(kivy,python)

Tags: python, kivy

How can i know number of page in pagelayout(kivy,python)For instance ,when user choose 3th page number of 'page' var will be 3.Please help

Answer (score 1):

## Page Numbering in PageLayout

In ***PageLayout***, the first page has a page number of 0. The third page is 2. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Total Pages in PageLayout

Use ***for loop*** to determine the total number of pages in a PageLayout.

### Snippets - PageLayout is Root

```
    for page in self.children:
        print(page)
```

### Snippets - PageLayout is not Root

```
    for child in self.children:
        if isinstance(child, PageLayout):
            for page in child.children:
                print(page)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout


class RootWidget(PageLayout):

    def print_page(self, btn):
        print("{0} has a page number = {1}".format(btn.text, self.page))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<RootWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'page1'
        on_release: root.print_page(self)
    Button:
        text: 'page2'
        on_release: root.print_page(self)
    Button:
        text: 'page3'
        on_release: root.print_page(self)
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - page1 has page number 0]
[image: Img02 - page3 has page number 2]